# Override javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I want to override js function in this way:

```
var elements = {
  "Element": {
    name: Element,
    events: ["focus","blur"]
  },
  "Window": {
    name: Window,
    events: ["scroll"]
  }
}

$.each(elements, function( k, v ) {
  $.each(v.events, function( i, val ) {
    if (val) {
      console.log(v.name.prototype[val]);

      v.name.prototype[val] = function () {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Update: fixed, does anyone have suggestions how to make it better?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fh4qxz7/3/)

Comment: The things in your elements array (Element, Window) aren't instances of a class. They're just objects. That means they don't have a prototype anymore than `a = {};` has a prototype.

Comment: So, if i change: `name: "Element"` to `name: Element`, then all will be fine?

Comment: We can't help make it better, if we don't know the intended use case. What are you attempting to do? It seems a little unorthodox.

Comment: I have a lot iframe on page, that show preview for pages, I'm blocking certain events inside iframe by override.

Answer (score 0):

The things in your elements array (Element, Window) aren't instances of a class. They're just objects. That means they don't have a prototype anymore than `a = {};` has a prototype.

If you change those strings to point to class definitions, then your code should work. So...

```
var elements = {
  "Element": {
    class: Element,
    events: ["focus","blur"]
  },
  "Window": {
    class: Window,
    events: ["scroll"]
  }
}

$.each(elements, function( k, v ) {
  $.each(v.events, function( i, val ) {
    if (val) {
      v.class.prototype[val] = function () {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

All that being said.. your code seems a bit bizarre to me. Why are you trying to override the default `Window` and `Element` prototype?